# Change css class in angular outside of controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to make an angularjs app responsive and having difficulty with changing css class names that are associated with other controllers, from within a different controller on a state change. How is this possible? All suggestions welcome!

## Specifically:

I have a site structure that can have up to 4 columns showing. Each column has a different ui-router-state, template, and controller. Depending on the routing state, or number of other columns viewable, the css classname associated with the other columns' divs will need to change. I'm looking for a way to change the classname `4-col` from within the routing state controller of the column. (Each column is a child of the column before it.)

**Example: 4 columns**

```
<div class="wrap 4-col"
  <nav role="navigation">1st Column</nav>
  <main role="site">
    <article role="list">2nd Column</article>
    <article role="list">3rd Column</article>
    <article role="main">4th Column</article>
  </main>
</div>
```

**Example: 3 columns**

```
<div class="wrap 3-col"
  <nav role="navigation">1st Column</nav>
  <main role="site">
    <article role="list">2nd Column</article>
    <article role="list">3rd Column</article>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into directives - they are basically controller scopes that you can apply anywhere, and then have them watch/listen for certain events that would cause a class change.

Comment: @jraede not entirely true, but close. Directives can create an **isolate scope**, which in some ways is similar to a controller's scope. They can also bind to particular controllers and access their scopes directly. However, they are not really like controllers themselves. They define an encapsulated piece of reusable functionality.

Comment: Jeffrey, I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to do. What do you mean when you say "changing css class names that are associated with other controllers"? Controllers are somewhat detached from DOM interactions, there shouldn't be css class associated with them. Like @jraede said, that's what directives are for.

Comment: I added an example in the question.